# Bug in the "History" tab of "Close votes"?

Tags: bug, closing

1) I am presented with a question submitted for closure review.

2) I open the link in another browser tab, in order to also read the answers given there and have a better understanding of the issue.

3) While on this page, I vote to close the question as a duplicate. Clicking again "close" in order to verify that my vote has been registered I see that indeed it has - the counter of the votes to "close as a duplicate" has increased from 0 to 1, and I am presented with the option to retract my vote. Fine, MSE seems to have registered it.

4) Strangely, this vote does not appear in my closing votes history. It is as if it didn't exist. Strangely too, my name doesn't appear among those who voted on that question.

Is this a bug, or some counterintuitive intended behaviour?

Comment: 16 minutes later, is the problem fixed? Many many times it's simply an issue with caching and the discrepancy is fixed after a while.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: No, it's still not there. The question is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443152/is-a-whole-number-a-rational-number.

Comment: Strange. You're looking [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=closure&page=1), right?

Comment: You voted on the page, not from the queue. Thus your close vote doesn't appear in the queue's history. But your name is listed among the closers of that question, as it ought to.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: No. I'm looking at "Review -> Close Votes -> history". Strange, indeed, but maybe the answer is the one given by Daniel Fischer above. By the way, in the page referred by you, why is there a "(deleted)" below each "closure"?

Comment: @AlexM. Yes, it's very probably Daniel's answer that's correct. The history for the review queue only shows the history for... the review queue, not all the people who voted to close every question. The "(deleted)" means that your close vote was deleted, either because the question was closed (and so the close vote count is reset to zero) or it expired after a few days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Daniel Fischer explained, the [review transcript](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/478654) and the overall [review history](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/history) list only review actions. A vote cast from the question page (i.e., outside of review) is not a review action. It does not get credited toward reviewing badges, either.